# Minimal executable to have a working ld-linux in memory

Tags: linux-kernel, linker, ld, elf, glibc

I have a somewhat unusual question to the Linux/glibc folks here: What are the “minimally” needed segments that cause the kernel to load an ld-linux into memory and also cause the ld-linux to relocate itself (including `_dl_open` and `_dl_lookup_symbol_x`)?

The code is kind of hard to understand and work through, maybe someone of you has a deeper knowledge of this stuff and can help. :)

EDIT: As far as I can tell by now, it seems like ld crashes, if `PT_DYNAMIC` is not at least present.

Comment: The ELF-format executable will need at least a `PT_INTERP` section that names the loader, as described in [Dynamic Linking](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.dynamic.html).

Answer (score 1):

> What are the “minimally” needed segments that cause the kernel to load an ld-linux into memory and also cause the ld-linux to relocate itself.

The kernel will `mmap` `ld-linux` (or any other binary) the path to which is contained in the `PT_INTERP` segment of the main executable.

The kernel will then transfer control to the interpreter entry point (instead of `a.out` entry point).

It is up to the interpreter to relocate itself; the kernel has nothing to do with that.